# is it possible to query a php page in jquery mobile if its been hashed?

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, navigation

for instance, something like this:

```
<li id="nameView">
   <a href='view.php?mode=name' data-prefetch onclick='setEventView()'>
    <h1>Today's Schedule By Name</h1>
    <p>List of classes and events sorted by name</p>
   </a>
</li>
```

works for me but in the page containg that im doing a "include 'feedback.php';"
which works fine, only now I want to be able to pass the hashed feedback page, parameters from the page visited prior to it being opened. 
So instead of :

```
<li><a data-transition="slideup" href="#feedback">Feedback</a></li>
```

I want to do something like:

```
<li><a data-transition="slideup" href="#feedback? lastPageVisited="blahblahblah">Feedback</a></li>
```

or

```
<li><a data-transition="slideup" href="feedback.php?lastPageVisited="blahblahblah">Feedback</a></li>
```

except that none of those work and I don't want to constantly prefetch or link to the feedback.php page.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The hash portion of a url must always be at the end of the url, so

```
example.com?hi=there#buddy
```

would be correct, while

```
example.com#buddy?how=goes
```

is incorrect. After a `#` is encountered in a url, everything after it becomes part of the has value, and is not sent to the server by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

In a jQuery Mobile website, each pseudo-page is given a `data-url` attribute that either references the id of the element (this is for when you have multiple pseudo-pages in a single HTML document) or the location of the original document (when this is done jQuery Mobile stores an absolute URL as the `data-url` attribute). When you navigate to a page the framework first checks to see if the document is in the DOM before pulling it in via AJAX, you can try to use this by changing your links to absolute URLs:

```
<li><a data-transition="slideup" href="/path/to/feedback.php">Feedback</a></li>
```